# Open-source, easy to learn PHP framework able to produce nice looking lists

Tags: open-source, php, framework

I want to write an small app for meeting and task organization. Nothing too complex. Only a few users which can take over tasks, join meetings, and some managers who create tasks and meetings. In addition a bit of statistics, showing available meetings, tasks (by category). Fancy stuff like swimmlanes is not needed. Meetings and tasks are mostly text, a date and persons.

For this I want to use a small PHP framework/microframework that has the following features:

- User management
- Stable and secure
- Well documented (existing community is a plus)
- Easy to learn for an advanced programmer (object orientation is a plus)
- Open-source
- Either supports display of nicely looking lists (and filtering by category) OR
- Works well together with a Javascript library (which one) that allows nicely looking lists
- compactness of the framework is a plus

Comment: To be honest, I don't see that you need a framework for this. It might just get in your way and add a learning curve. Is it really so difficult to do this in pure PHP? Even then, you could still format  it client-side with JS.  Bonus tip, for MySql access, use PDO.

Comment: @Mawg Thank you for the comment. This is surely also an option. However I have some time for learning a framework - it will pay off later I guess. Surely there are some things that you don't need to do yourself when using a framework, so it would probably be an option, especially if you want to learn one and if you want to be able to extend your app later on.

Comment: See my similar question: CodeIgniter is being replaced by Lavarel, but in the end I did it all client-side with AngularJs ... http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16426/stable-well-supported-php-framework-with-possibly-form-builder-and-graphs-char